# How does an FBO refer to the parking spots on the ramp?

Tags: fbo

How does an FBO refer to the parking spots on the ramp? What is the official term? And is there some sort of an identifier, a "ramp number"? Is this standardized, like runway numbers, or does it vary from FBO to FBO? Are there numbers painted on the ramp?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the airports I've flown into, it's usually, you're just guided into a spot, and most often, there aren't any lines there, mainly since an FBO should be able to generally serve something as small as a Cessna, to a Gulfstream, or bigger. Flight School Ramps might have painted lines and dedicated parking for their fleet, but they know who will be parking there and what type.

Comment: You are right.  Usually it is "park it next to the Mooney at the end of the line, over there <points thataway>